# When run AVD via primusrun, I getting " version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found" and via optirun, I getting CXXABI_"1.3.* not found"

Tags: android, c++, linux, fedora, android-virtual-device

I using Fedora 27 and my laptop support hybrid graphic card

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M] [10de:0fd2] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)

$ uname -r
4.15.4-300.fc27.x86_64
```

I want to use my nvidia GPU to emulate AVD, which I believe will be more efficient. I already have bumblebee installed and it working fine.

So I tried with primus run

```
$ primusrun /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_27 -verbose
emulator:Android emulator version 26.0.3.0 (build_id 3965150)
emulator:Found AVD name 'Nexus_5X_API_27'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator:argv[0]: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/emulator'; program directory: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools'
emulator:  Found directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator:Probing for /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu: file exists
emulator:Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (based on configuration)
emulator:  Found directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator:try dir /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools
emulator:try dir /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/
emulator:try dir /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator
emulator:Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/libstdc++'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Running :/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-netdelay"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "none"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "-netspeed"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[04] = "full"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[05] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[06] = "Nexus_5X_API_27"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[07] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386 -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_27 -verbose
/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib64/primus/libGL.so.1)
```

It said **version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib64/primus/libGL.so.1)**

I check string of emulator library

```
$ strings /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
```

and my machine

```
$ strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.24 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
```

I also tried with optirun

```
$ optirun /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_27 -verbose
emulator:Android emulator version 26.0.3.0 (build_id 3965150)
emulator:Found AVD name 'Nexus_5X_API_27'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator:argv[0]: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/emulator'; program directory: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools'
emulator:  Found directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator:Probing for /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu: file exists
emulator:Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (based on configuration)
emulator:  Found directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator:try dir /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools
emulator:try dir /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/
emulator:try dir /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator
emulator:Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/libstdc++'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Running :/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-netdelay"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "none"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "-netspeed"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[04] = "full"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[05] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[06] = "Nexus_5X_API_27"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[07] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386 -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_27 -verbose
/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib64/VirtualGL/librrfaker.so)
/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/lib64/VirtualGL/librrfaker.so)
```

and getting version **CXXABI_1.3.8** and **CXXABI_1.3.9 not found** 
Please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Firstly need to checked if the **libstdc++.so.6** was available in the shared library cache:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libstdc++.so.6 
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

Check the program file details

```
$ file /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/emulator
/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/emulator: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

It is 64-bit LSB executable.

I need to symlink my AVD library with my machine

```
$ cd /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/
$ ls -l | grep libstd
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4831936 Feb  5 17:16 libstdc++.so.6
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4831936 Feb  5 17:16 libstdc++.so.6.0.19
```

Create a backup of **libstdc++.so.6**

```
$ mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

Then check my `/usr/lib` library

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/ | grep libstd
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   263400 Aug 16  2014 libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       31 Aug 16  2014 libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 -> libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       18 Feb 10  2017 libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   743796 Feb 10  2017 libstdc++.so.5.0.7
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       19 Jan 30 21:31 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.24
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  1586468 Jan 30 21:35 libstdc++.so.6.0.24
```

Now create symlink to current directory

```
$ pwd
/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/libstdc++    
$ ln -fs /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6  libstdc++.so.6
```

Checking shared lib

```
 $ ldd /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/emulator
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe62798000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007effa086c000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007effa0669000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007effa0461000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007effa0242000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007eff9feed000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007eff9fcd6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007eff9f8f3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007effa0a70000)
```

Now run the emulator via primusrun

```
$ optirun /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_27 -verbose
emulator:Android emulator version 26.0.3.0 (build_id 3965150)
emulator:Found AVD name 'Nexus_5X_API_27'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator:argv[0]: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/emulator'; program directory: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools'
emulator:  Found directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator:Probing for /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu: file exists
emulator:Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (based on configuration)
emulator:  Found directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator:try dir /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools
emulator:try dir /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/tools/
emulator:try dir /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator
emulator:Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator:Adding library search path: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/libstdc++'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Running :/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-netdelay"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "none"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "-netspeed"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[04] = "full"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[05] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[06] = "Nexus_5X_API_27"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[07] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386 -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_27 -verbose
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: using snapshot lock path: /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/snapshot.lock
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 27
emulator: Read property file at /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: found skin 'nexus_5x' in directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/skins/
emulator: autoconfig: -skin nexus_5x
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/skins/
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img
emulator: Using initial vendor image: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//vendor.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1536MB

emulator: VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 384MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 2 DNS servers: 192.168.161.1 192.168.161.4
emulator: trying to load skin file '/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/skins//nexus_5x/layout'
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: Found 2 DNS servers: 192.168.161.1 192.168.161.4
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.cpu.model = qemu32
  hw.cpu.ncore = 4
  hw.ramSize = 1536
  hw.screen = multi-touch
  hw.mainKeys = false
  hw.trackBall = false
  hw.keyboard = true
  hw.keyboard.lid = false
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = false
  hw.rotaryInput = false
  hw.gsmModem = true
  hw.gps = true
  hw.battery = true
  hw.accelerometer = true
  hw.gyroscope = true
  hw.audioInput = true
  hw.audioOutput = true
  hw.sdCard = true
  hw.sdCard.path = /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = true
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  test.quitAfterBootTimeOut = -1
  hw.lcd.width = 1080
  hw.lcd.height = 1920
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 420
  hw.lcd.backlight = true
  hw.gpu.enabled = true
  hw.gpu.mode = host
  hw.gpu.blacklisted = no
  hw.initialOrientation = Portrait
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = emulated
  vm.heapSize = 384
  hw.sensors.light = true
  hw.sensors.pressure = true
  hw.sensors.humidity = true
  hw.sensors.proximity = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field_uncalibrated = true
  hw.sensors.gyroscope_uncalibrated = true
  hw.sensors.orientation = true
  hw.sensors.temperature = true
  hw.useext4 = true
  hw.arc = false
  hw.arc.autologin = false
  kernel.path = /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 2562m
  disk.vendorPartition.initPath = /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//vendor.img
  disk.vendorPartition.size = 200m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 2g
  disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path = /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/encryptionkey.img
  PlayStore.enabled = true
  avd.name = Nexus_5X_API_27
  fastboot.forceColdBoot = false
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386"
emulator: argv[01] = "-dns-server"
emulator: argv[02] = "192.168.161.1,192.168.161.4"
emulator: argv[03] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[04] = "null"
emulator: argv[05] = "-device"
emulator: argv[06] = "goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin"
emulator: argv[07] = "-cpu"
emulator: argv[08] = "android32"
emulator: argv[09] = "-enable-kvm"
emulator: argv[10] = "-smp"
emulator: argv[11] = "cores=4"
emulator: argv[12] = "-m"
emulator: argv[13] = "1536"
emulator: argv[14] = "-lcd-density"
emulator: argv[15] = "420"
emulator: argv[16] = "-object"
emulator: argv[17] = "iothread,id=disk-iothread"
emulator: argv[18] = "-nodefaults"
emulator: argv[19] = "-kernel"
emulator: argv[20] = "/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu"
emulator: argv[21] = "-initrd"
emulator: argv[22] = "/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//ramdisk.img"
emulator: argv[23] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[24] = "if=none,index=0,id=system,file=/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img,read-only"
emulator: argv[25] = "-device"
emulator: argv[26] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[27] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[28] = "if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[29] = "-device"
emulator: argv[30] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[31] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[32] = "if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[33] = "-device"
emulator: argv[34] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[35] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[36] = "if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,file=/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[37] = "-device"
emulator: argv[38] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[39] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[40] = "if=none,index=4,id=vendor,file=/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//vendor.img,read-only"
emulator: argv[41] = "-device"
emulator: argv[42] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[43] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[44] = "if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,file=/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[45] = "-device"
emulator: argv[46] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[47] = "-netdev"
emulator: argv[48] = "user,id=mynet"
emulator: argv[49] = "-device"
emulator: argv[50] = "virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet"
emulator: argv[51] = "-device"
emulator: argv[52] = "virtio-rng-pci"
emulator: argv[53] = "-show-cursor"
emulator: argv[54] = "-L"
emulator: argv[55] = "/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib/pc-bios"
emulator: argv[56] = "-soundhw"
emulator: argv[57] = "hda"
emulator: argv[58] = "-vga"
emulator: argv[59] = "none"
emulator: argv[60] = "-append"
emulator: argv[61] = "qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=288M@0-4G ndns=2 androidboot.android_dt_dir=/sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/ ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000"
emulator: argv[62] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[63] = "/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386 -dns-server 192.168.161.1,192.168.161.4 -serial null -device goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin -cpu android32 -enable-kvm -smp cores=4 -m 1536 -lcd-density 420 -object iothread,id=disk-iothread -nodefaults -kernel /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu -initrd /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//ramdisk.img -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,file=/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,file=/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=4,id=vendor,file=/mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//vendor.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,file=/home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -device virtio-rng-pci -show-cursor -L /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/emulator/lib/pc-bios -soundhw hda -vga none -append 'qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=288M@0-4G ndns=2 androidboot.android_dt_dir=/sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/ ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000' -android-hw /home/rnm/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Android qemu version 27.1.10.0 (build_id 4607264) (CL:2312b3ec8e08a7a44dc6ce6092f664a09cabf93c)

emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'both'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.adb.secure' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '384m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '420'
emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-camera: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-keyboard: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-touch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-multitouch: true
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Not using any http proxy
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

emulator: found skin 'nexus_5x' in directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/skins/
emulator: found skin 'nexus_5x' in directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/skins/
emulator: found skin 'nexus_5x' in directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/skins/
emulator: found skin 'nexus_5x' in directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/skins/
emulator: _hwFingerprint_connect: connect finger print listen is called

emulator: got message from guest system fingerprint HAL

emulator: found skin 'nexus_5x' in directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/skins/
emulator: onGuestSendCommand: [0x7f6254141b80] Adb connected, start proxing data
emulator: found skin 'nexus_5x' in directory: /mnt/01D19F269DAADFD0/Android/Sdk-linux/skins/
emulator: onGuestClose: [0x7f6254141b80] Adb closed by guest
emulator: onGuestClose: [0x7f62554a5ac0] Adb closed by guest
emulator: Done with QEMU main loop
emulator: User-config was not changed.
```

[image: AVD]
It worked for both optirun and primusrun!

Comment: Thanks for this, is a day saver! Cheers!